# Designing a "pop-out" interface that automatically updates - even possible?

Tags: php, javascript

So I developed this web application, which has several multiple select boxes on an admin page - each of these boxes contains multiple values, which we will call criteria.

The criteria in these boxes are generated on a form on another page and stored separately in another table in the database. The big problem is that my boss wants to have a new criteria editing page pop out in a new window, or a different tab of the same browser, allow the user to add one or multiple criteria, and have these update in the main admin browser window in real-time.

Now, if it was in the same window, my immediate thoughts would go to AJAX. However, because it will be in two separate browser windows, I don't believe this is a feasible solution.

Is there anyway (other than some form of COM programming or other OS-y methods, which I don't want to get into) to pass a value between the two browser windows, without having to reload the main page? That is a critical issue here - the main page cannot be reloaded at all during this process.

Would frames be the answer (thus getting rid of the dual browser window problem by not having two windows)? Something else? This is beyond my range of experience.

Comment: If you open the browser window, then you can call JS functions on the parent window to do the update. Then you can do whatever AJAX you need in the main window to update the data.

Comment: First of all, your boss is probably not a programmer is he? Secondly, although I would advise against this in the current situation, you could use a polling style service. Frame2 updates, sends update data as a 'command' to database, Frame1 polls the database for new 'commands' and executes the changes.

Comment: How would I call a JS function from the child window to the parent window?

Comment: My boss is an artist. That being said, I *imagine* he can at least program a little.

Comment: I agree with Micheal, through standard javascript and some ajax (jquery may be your best bet on that part) You can load a new window and basicly bind functionality to the parent that opened it. Its a bit tricky but possible. Getting it to open in a new tab vs a new window thats a bit more difficult, and also depends on the browser and settings there in. If your boss wants a pop-up why not just do a lightbox or similar to achieve the same thing within the same window. The plus to doing it this way is most modern browsers block external popups.

Comment: a lightbox? And I am not against theoretically doing it in the same browser window.

Comment: Neither would he be. Implementation, as long as it is "aroundish" what I've described to you here, is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: http://www.plus2net.com/javascript_tutorial/window-child3.php and http://www.codeproject.com/KB/scripting/JS_ParentChild.aspx might be a bit helpful in figuring out how to do it with standalone javascript

Comment: good example of a lightbox http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/

Comment: all in all though what I am trying to say with the popup thing is, you may not personally run into conflict building it but I garentee a lot of your clients will. As most people on the internet use the stock configurations of there OS which if its windows can be locked tight. Also with that a lot of people use browsers that block popups by defualt. You can't control settings like that client side and you will end up with more headache then you want when the boss figures out this isnt working for a lot of people

Answer (score 0):

Possible solutions:

1. Frames (probably the simplest, works with old browsers too)
2. [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29) (emulated JavaScript push notifications)
3. Mootools [`Request.Periodical`](http://mootools.net/docs/more/Request/Request.Periodical)
4. [HTML5 Web Sockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) (the "best" but works only in the newest browsers)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you might be able to look into fsockopen() and see if a php socket solution could be useful in this case, but that may not be necessary since the skill level of sockets is - in my opinion - considerably higher than running a basic ajax request in your new frame to check if the form has changed within the last 5 seconds.

You can create a table in a database to represent a user's form and store the current values in that table along side a token that regenerates on each update. That way when you pop up your new screen that is supposed to live update you also send the form id and the first token. Then that window makes a basic ajax call every 5 seconds to see if the token for that form id has changed since the last call. If so, return a json object with all the info you need and update accordingly. If not, return false and do nothing.

This is just one possibility. It might be a lot of unnecessary db calls but then again - I don't know the purpose of this request so I don't know how absurd this solution is relative to your needs.

Comment: More or less the purpose is to allow a user to say "Hey, this non-profit organization doesn't have one of its associated services listed here in this multiple select box, I will add it immediately!" without having to reload or losing their data.

Comment: well that's easy. You could just create a modal screen and popuplate it with the form necessary for creating the associated service, then on submit - close the modal box and repopulate the multiple select box. Naturally it depends on everything else that depends on this situation, but ultimately it is not unreasonable to do this with basic jquery and - say - lightbox. I believe someone mentioned that above.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled across a usage of the localstorage (DOM storage) API for [sharing messages across windows](http://www.codediesel.com/javascript/sharing-messages-and-data-across-windows-using-localstorage). I don't know how much data you need to send, and there are some compatibility concerns (support in IE starts in IE8, other browsers have good support for some versions now). Basically, each page would have an "onstorage" event handler set, so that a modification to a store (add, delete, modify/update) in one window would trigger the event in the other window as well. Of course, this is limited to the same origin. From how you described what you need, this sounds like it might be a valid solution.

Answer (score 0):

Once you open a window using

```
var new_window = window.open(...);
```

then `new_window` is a reference to the window object in the new window, and from the new window `window.opener` is a reference to the window object in the original window. Subject to the same-domain security policy you'll be able to call functions "across the divide"

Comment: Everything should be on the same domain.